# cannot drag window created with divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag

hey there i am trying to drag the following window

[image]

with the following codes:

```
var zindex = 0;
var dragobject = {
    z: 0, 
    x: 0, 
    y: 0, 
    offsetx: null, 
    offsety: null, 
    targetobj: null, 
    dragapproved: 0,
    initialize:function(){
        document.onmousedown=this.drag
        document.onmouseup=function(){this.dragapproved=0}
    },
    drag:function(e){
        var evtobj=window.event? window.event : e
        this.targetobj=window.event? event.srcElement : e.target

        if (this.targetobj.className=="drag"){
            this.dragapproved=1
            zindex = zindex + 1;
            $("#" + this.targetobj.id).css('z-index', zindex);
            //document.getElementById(this.targetobj.id).style.zIndex='1'

            if (isNaN(parseInt(this.targetobj.style.left))) {
                this.targetobj.style.left=0
            }

            if (isNaN(parseInt(this.targetobj.style.top))) {
                this.targetobj.style.top=0
            }

            this.offsetx=parseInt(this.targetobj.style.left)
            this.offsety=parseInt(this.targetobj.style.top)
            this.x=evtobj.clientX
            this.y=evtobj.clientY

            if (evtobj.preventDefault)
                evtobj.preventDefault()
                document.onmousemove=dragobject.moveit
            }
        },
        moveit:function(e){
            var evtobj=window.event? window.event : e

            if (this.dragapproved==1){
                this.targetobj.style.left=this.offsetx+evtobj.clientX-this.x+"px"
                this.targetobj.style.top=this.offsety+evtobj.clientY-this.y+"px"
                return false
            }
        }
    }

dragobject.initialize()
```

the css:

```
.heading{
    background: rgb(69,72,77); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(69,72,77,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#45484d', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.drag{
position:relative;
cursor:hand;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div style="background:#eeeeee; height:500px; width:400px; border-radius:5px; border:0px solid #8d8d8d; border-top:0px; box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);" id="window1">

            <!-- Window Heading -->
            <div id="window1x" class="heading drag" style="height:32px;border-top-right-radius:5px;border-top-left-radius:5px;" align="center">

                <div style="padding-top:6px;font-size:15px;color:#FFF;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #000;">Window</div>

                <!-- Close, Maximize, Minimize Button -->

                <!-- End Of Close, Maximize, Minimize Button -->

            </div>
            <!-- End Of Window Heading -->



        </div>
```

but it doesn't seem to work, i mean i can drag the window when the `drag` css is in the div with `id="window1"` but i cannot drag it with the black header, i have to drag it with the white space in the window, hope i made myself clear. when the `drag` css is in the div with `id="window1x"` i cannot drag the window at all as shown in the html code above, as a matter of fact i cannot drag anything. can anyone please tell me how to get around this. thanks!

P.S i found the dragging code by viewing the example source code from [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/image3.htm)

Comment: why not use jQuery UI lib? it supports `draggable` and can save you much time implementing it yourself. Here you are http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ , once you're familiar with jQuery, using jQuery UI is in fact simple (the learning curve is nearly a horizontal line, don't be afraid like when you feel the very steep learning curve of ***WPF*** :)

Comment: can't i do it without using jQuery UI!

Comment: of course as I said, using jQuery UI is the fastest way, writing code yourself is possible but it at least takes about several hours to more of your time.

Comment: hey.. least i learned something new !

Comment: do you have an example that matches my problem!

Comment: With you JS code now idented, it seems that you're missing a closing `}`.

Comment: Use the browser debug console, usually `F12` or right click and `Inspect Element` to debug your JavaScript code.

Comment: _"Doesn't work"_ is impossibly ambiguous, explain what specific issue you're facing. Adding a bounty doesn't mean you can just throw code at people and ask for a fix.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Roy_S/pCqNn/ is that better.. try dragging it with the title bar.. P.S i was having lunch.. sorry to keep you guys waiting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Adding `pointer-events: none;` to the CSS of your header bar.

So:

```
.heading {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will allow click events to pass through to the actual container div that does the dragging.

See **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pCqNn/1/)**.
Warning: This will not work in IE10 or below.

Comment: could you do me a small little favour.. your code works flawlessly but i can't seem to get the buttons in the title bar working when i use your code could you take a look into it..  http://jsfiddle.net/Roy_S/pCqNn/3/  thanks!

Comment: You'll have to restore pointer events for any children that need it. So in your case adding `pointer-events: auto;` under `.windowButtons` does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/pCqNn/4/